# avconv gets killed if mkv has subtitles

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles, libav, audio-conversion

What I'm trying to do is to take a movie (in an Matroska container), convert all audio tracks to AC3 and don't touch anything else. I'm using this line:

```
avconv -i infile.mkv -map 0 -vcodec copy -scodec copy -acodec ac3 -ab 256k outfile.mkv
```

This works fine, except when there are subtitles embedded. Then, after some time processing with no progress, `avconv` just "dies" (output shortened, these seem to be the interesting parts):

```
[matroska,webm @ 0xf867a0] max_analyze_duration reached
[matroska,webm @ 0xf867a0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
...
Incompatible sample format 's16' for codec 'ac3', auto-selecting format 'flt'
...
Stream #0.0(eng): Video: H264 / 0x34363248, yuv420p, 1280x536 [PAR 1:1 DAR 160:67], q=2-31, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Stream #0.1(ger): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1, flt, 256 kb/s (default)
    Stream #0.2(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1, flt, 256 kb/s
    Stream #0.3(ger): Subtitle: dvdsub (default) (forced)
    Metadata:
      title           : forced
    Stream #0.4(ger): Subtitle: dvdsub
    Metadata:
      title           : complete
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (dca -> ac3)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (dca -> ac3)
  Stream #0:3 -> #0:3 (copy)
  Stream #0:4 -> #0:4 (copy)
Input stream #0:2 frame changed from rate:48000 fmt:s16 ch:6 to rate:48000 fmt:flt ch:6
Input stream #0:1 frame changed from rate:48000 fmt:s16 ch:6 to rate:48000 fmt:flt ch:6
frame= 2606 fps=1303 q=-1.0 size=       3kB time=107.36 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s   
...
frame=96141 fps=813 q=-1.0 size= 2195806kB time=2807.04 bitrate=6408.2kbits/s
frame=96251 fps=810 q=-1.0 size= 2195806kB time=2807.04 bitrate=6408.2kbits/s
...
frame=97015 fps=397 q=-1.0 size= 2195806kB time=2807.04 bitrate=6408.2kbits/s
Getötet ["Killed", in English]
```

I have no idea why this happens, as there is no error-output.

I'd like to just copy the subtitles over, not touch them at all. If that won't work, they can be completely dropped.

Comment: Please always post the full, uncut command line output, not only the parts you think are relevant – especially the version and build information. Of course the repeating lines with the 90,000 frames can be left out. That being said, have you tried to do the same with a recent [static build of `ffmpeg`](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) or `avconv`? Chances are you're just seeing a bug that was already fixed.

Comment: @slhck nope, I'm using what's in the Ubuntu standard repos. `version 0.8.7-6:0.8.7-1ubuntu2 -- built on Oct 11 2013 08:39:40 with gcc 4.8.1`. I'm also a little confused that you linked to the ffmpeg builds, I thought that program was deprecated?

Comment: @slhck I tried `ffmpeg` from [here](https://launchpad.net/~jon-severinsson/+archive/ffmpeg), but no luck with that either (same problem as above).

Comment: Unfortunate wording, but FFmpeg is far from dead and – as you can see – actively maintained. The Libav maintainers only thought it was clever to tell everyone FFmpeg was deprecated. See: [Who can tell me the difference and relation between ffmpeg, libav, and avconv?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477115/) Anyway, I don't know if the PPAs serve a recent-ish version. Please try with a *static build*, like I asked, and include the entire command line output. You can get one here, for example: http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/

Comment: Unfortunately that PPA only offers the 0.10 or 0.7 release branches which are unsuitable for most "check to see if a bug is fixed yet" type of testing. If a recent real ffmpeg also does not work as expected then please provide a sample input if possible.

Comment: You possibly need to install more codecs. Take a look at [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2002893) discussion.

Comment: I just tried it with another file which has `PGS`-subtitles and that seems to work fine. Not sure if it's because I installed the package mentioned by @Rajib but that could be a hint. I'll try the static builds as soon as I have time.

Comment: @slhck The static build you linked work just fine, seems that it's really just a bug. If you put that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `version 0.8.7-6:0.8.7-1ubuntu2` of "ffmpeg" [is not really ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9477756/435093) but a buggy version of Libav shipped under the wrong name.

Most problems where you *know* it should work but it fails for some reason are usually fixed in the latest builds, which you can easily get by:

- [compiling yourself](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/CompilationGuide) (it's not that hard)
- Downloading [a static build](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) (not the PPA or any distribution packages)